# Difference between initializing a function pointer in Rust using method, associated function and a free function

Tags: rust

This question is following up from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370120/right-way-to-have-function-pointers-in-struct).

As a novice in Rust, I am trying to understand the way a function pointer (fn) is initialized. Here's an abridged and much simpler description of the application I am writing.

A `Controller` is initialized with a `route: i32` value. Later, this value may be modified and all the old values are stored in a list, as a *history of changes*.

Here's a sample 'lib.rs` content:

```
use futures::future;
use random_number::random;



pub struct Controller {
    pub route: i32,
    pub running_history_modified_routes: Vec<i32>
}

impl Controller {

     // a 'route' is initialized with an integer
     pub fn new(p: i32) -> Controller {
         Controller { route: p, running_history_modified_routes: Vec::new()}
     }

     // Subsequently, the 'route' may get a new value.
     // Here, we are generating a random new value and storing that in
     // vector, as history of changes to route.
     pub fn compute_a_new_route (&mut self, using_seed: i32) -> &mut Controller {

            // My confusion is around this initialization!
            let as_function_pointer: fn(i32) -> i32 = free_function_generate_random_route_value;

            let a_fresh_route = self.get_a_route_afresh(using_seed,as_function_pointer);
            self.running_history_modified_routes.push(a_fresh_route);
            self

     }

     fn get_a_route_afresh(&self, seed_as_higher_limit: i32, f:fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
             f(seed_as_higher_limit)
     }

     fn method_generate_random_route_value(&self,seed_as_higher_limit: i32) -> i32 {
         random!(0 as i32, seed_as_higher_limit)
     }

    fn assoc_function_generate_random_route_value(seed_as_higher_limit: i32) -> i32 {
        random!(0 as i32, seed_as_higher_limit)
    }
}

fn free_function_generate_random_route_value(seed_as_higher_limit: i32) -> i32 {
    random!(0 as i32, seed_as_higher_limit)
}
```

`fn get_a_route_afresh(..)` receives a function pointer and calls it to get the new route value (which is a random number, for this example, of course :-) ).

I have three different candidates for the function pointer (commented in the code above):

- Controller's implementation method `method_generate_random_route_value`
- Controller's associated function `assoc_function_generate_random_route_value`
- Module's free function `free_function_generate_random_route_value`

My understanding is that each of these can be used for initializing a function pointer before calling `self.get_a_route_afresh(using_seed,as_function_pointer)`, in the **same way**! But, the compiler disagrees when I do this:

```
let as_function_pointer: fn(i32) -> i32 = self.method_generate_random_route_value;
```

and tells me this:

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `method_generate_random_route_value` on type `&mut Controller`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:60
   |
20 |             let as_function_pointer: fn(i32) -> i32 = self.method_generate_random_route_value;
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
20 |             let as_function_pointer: fn(i32) -> i32 = self.method_generate_random_route_value(_);
   |                                                                                              +++
```

Of course, when I use the associated or free function, both the compiler and I, are happy.

What is it that I am missing about a (*impl*) method's applicability when a function pointer is expected?

Here's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "FutureExperiment"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[dependencies]
random-number = "0.1.8"


[lib]
name="function_pointers_experiment"
path="src/lib.rs"
```

Comment: Unlike e.g. python rust doesn't have "instance method" values, `a.b` on a method is an error as you can see in your code. Because what Rust actually does is desugar to a "method call" to a static function call with the instance as first parameter e.g. `a.b()` is really `A::b(a)`. Therefore you can't take an instance method as a value. And if you could it would not be a *function pointer*: a function pointer is a free function with no associated data, but an instance method object would need to store the instance.

Comment: Thanks @Masklinn, for that brief yet clear explanation.. I should have been able to see that aspect of _desugaring_ . I had been a bit confused because of my background in Scala/Java, where an instance-level method can be used when a Method reference is expected.

Comment: FWIW you can take `Controller::get_a_route_afresh` as a value, and it'll be coercible to an `fn`, but that'll be an `fn(&Controller, i32) -> i32`, not just an `fn(i32) -> i32`, similar to taking a method reference on a type in Java. There is no instance method references, you have to use an explicit closure in order to capture `self`.

Comment: Yes! Got that.  @Masklinn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that binds `self` is not a function pointer. A function pointer `fn` (with a lowercase 'f') is a pointer to a top-level Rust function that *does not* close around any variables. Once you want to close around variables (even `self`), you no longer have a function pointer. Instead, you have a closure `Fn` (or `FnOnce` or `FnMut`, depending on how you close around variables). Top-level functions are function pointers, and associated functions (without a `self` binding) are really just top-level functions by another name.

If you want to accept any *callable* object, `FnMut` is a good place to start. Use `Fn` (with a capital 'F') if you need to call it concurrently (since `Fn` is forbidden from taking mutable references, it's safe to share in multiple places at once), or `FnOnce` if you need to take ownership of some values you can only use once. The type `fn` of function pointers is mainly used for low-level techniques that require an actual concrete pointer to some function, such as when interfacing with C code that doesn't know what a closure is.

Comment: The fact that 'self.method()' is a kind-of closure around 'self', is quite a conceptual shift, to me. Many thanks. That clarifies a lot. Thanks also for mentioning the Fn* family; I am familiar with them. Because of my background of C (and Scala/Java), a function pointer sits pretty well with my thinking. That's the reason, I have been exploring the fn of Rust here (as opposed to Fn).